# Button submitting form to "Get" ActionResult instead of "Post"

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I just took over a MVC Web Application for an employee who is no longer with the company I work for. The application is in the early development stage and I noticed an unresolved error where a 'submit' button triggers the view's corresponding HttpGet ActionResult, instead of the HttpPost ActionResult.

He included a lot of jQuery scripts in the view, and I originally suspected one of them could be causing the issue, however none seem to apply directly to the button.

Controller (named HomeController.cs):

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create(string distributorObject)
    {
        StockLiftObjectView stockLiftObjectView = new StockLiftObjectView();
        var userInfo = User.Identity.Name.GetActiveDirectoryInfo();
        stockLiftObjectView.txtFirstName = userInfo.FirstName;
        stockLiftObjectView.txtLastName = userInfo.LastName;
        stockLiftObjectView.txtEmail = userInfo.Email;

        if (stockLiftObjectView.RegionId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            stockLiftObjectView.RegionsList = new SelectList(_stockLiftService.GetRegions(), "Id", "RegionName");
        }

        return View(stockLiftObjectView);
    }

    [HttpPost] //Haven't done anything here yet. Ths is never reached
    public ActionResult Create(string command, StockLiftObjectView stockLiftObjectView)
    {
        return View(stockLiftObjectView);
    }
```

View (named Create.cshtml):

```
@using Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {id = createStockLift}))
{ 
    //left out some non-useful code here
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <table>
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Create" name="command" class="btn btn-default" /></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Save" name="command" class="btn btn-default" /></td></tr>
                </table>
    </div>
}
```

Script in View that I thought could be problematic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getview() {

        //runs everytime page loads

        $.get("@Url.Action("ShowPartial", "StockLiftAttachmentWebGrid",  new     List<hpd.Lynx.Web.StockLift.StockLiftAttachmentUpload>()))", function (data) {
            $("#stockliftattachmentpartial").replaceWith(data);
            $('#createStockLift').submit();
            });

        };
        $("#stockliftattachmentpartial").show();
</script>
```

I'm sorry my question isn't that specific. I've just been baffled by this issue for the past couple of days and can't think of a good way to describe the problem in a google search. As I said before, I'm not that well versed with jQuery so think I could be misunderstanding something simple.

UPDATE:

Only other time the getview() function is referenced is here...

```
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" title="Upload" id="btnUpload" onclick="javascript: getview(); return false;" />
```

so I don't understand why it executes when the page loads (I never click the upload button). Again, my misunderstanding is coming from never using more than basic scripts.

Other scripts in the view (don't seem applicable but I'll show in case)

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#search').click(function () {
            var distributorNumber = $("#textboxDistributorNumber").val();
            var href = this.href + '?distributorNumber=' + distributorNumber;
            @*var url = "@Url.Action("DistributorPartial", "Distributor")"*@
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                width: 1175,
                height: 500,
                title: 'Distributor Search',
                modal: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                    $(this).load(href, function (result) {
                        $('.forms').submit(function () {

                            $.ajax({
                                url: this.action,
                                type: this.method,
                                data: $(this).serialize(),
                                success: function (json) {
                                    debugger;
                                    $('#distributorViewModel_DistributorName').val(json.DistributorName);

                                }
                            });
                            return false;
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Create</title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://hco/css/Main.css" />
    

    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.7.2.js"></script>



    


    


   
  
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div align="center">
            <table border="0" width="800" bgcolor="black" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800px">
                            <tr bgcolor="black" height="60px">
                                                <%--ADD FILLER, SRM 2/13/2012--%>
                                <td align="left" class="appTitle" style="width:100%;">
                                    <!--the title was here-->
                                    
                                    
                                </td>
                                <td valign="top" align="right">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                           
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr valign="middle">
                                            <td><input style="padding:0,0,0,0;margin:0,0,0,0;" height="20px" type="text" name="txtSearch" id="txtSearch" /></td>
                                            <td><image height="22px" width="22px" style="background-color:White;padding:0,0,0,0;margin:0,0,0,0;" src="http://hco/images/SearchButton.jpg" alt="search" onclick="window.location='/site-search.aspx?search=' + document.all.txtSearch.value.trim()" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='hand'" />&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr height="24px">
                                <td colspan="2" class="hcoNav">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" height="24" width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                           
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                    <tr>
 
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3" bgcolor="white" height="100%" valign="top" style="margin:0,0,0,0;">
                                    <div style="padding:10px;">
                                        <div id="page">

                                            <div class="container body-content">
                                                


                                          





<form action="/Home/Create" id="createStockLift" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="xz4YzzvUUXUP-g5KCkPRb6Ox3dZ668tjmH6fKIIwL52zSnVjX-DfV0XDNVWaKMplGPCbm664TdiJDWwoWUeO70ET9nwsPGwsRv0DVxOgDyYLMA3d3CzvEh2Vzj0ftr6O0" />    <style type="text/css">
        .style1 {
            height: 35px;
        }
    </style>
    <br />
    <div id="lblRequired" align="center">
        <label for="lblRequired">* Required for saving</label>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
        <div style="text-align: left; clear: none;">
            <table cellpadding="2" border="1" align="center">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>*CTM First Name:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="textboxFirstName" id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="txtFirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>*CTM Last Name</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="textboxLastName" id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="txtLastName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>*CTM Email:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="textboxEmail" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="txtEmail" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>*Your Region:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select data-val="true" data-val-required="The RegionId field is required." id="RegionId" na               <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="RegionId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>*Distributor:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Distributor_Number_Search_Text:_">Distributor Number Search Text: </label>
                        <input id="textboxDistributorNumber" name="Distributor" type="text" value="" /> <br />
                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Distributor_Customer_Name_Search_Text:_">Distributor Customer Name Search Text: </label>
                        <input id="textboxDistributorName" name="DistributorPrincipalApprovalId" type="text" value="" />


                        <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">Please wait</div>
                        <a href="/Distributor/DistributorPartial" id="search">Search</a>
                        
                        <div id="divDistributor">
                            <input class="text-box single-line" id="distributorViewModel_DistributorName" name="distributorViewModel.DistributorName" type="text" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Distributor" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>End User:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="AccountManufactures">Account Manufactures:</label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="textboxAccountManufactures" id="AccountManufactures" name="AccountManufactures" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="AccountManufactures" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="InventoryRemovedFrom">Inventory removed from:</label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="textboxInventoyRemovedFrom" id="InventoryRemovedFrom" name="InventoryRemovedFrom" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="InventoryRemovedFrom" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="AnnualPotentialValue">*Annual potential for HPD products:</label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="textboxAnnualPotentialValue" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field *Annual potential for HPD products: must be a number." id="AnnualPotentialValue" name="AnnualPotentialValue" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="InventoryRemovedFrom" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="InventoryValue">*Competitive Inventory Value:</label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field *Competitive Inventory Value: must be a number." id="InventoryValue" name="InventoryValue" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="InventoryValue" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="FiftyPercentMultiplier">*50% (.50) Multiplier:</label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field *50% (.50) Multiplier: must be a number." id="FiftyPercentMultiplier" name="FiftyPercentMultiplier" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FiftyPercentMultiplier" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="CreditDueValue">*CREDIT DUE DISTRIBUTOR:</label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field *CREDIT DUE DISTRIBUTOR: must be a number." id="CreditDueValue" name="CreditDueValue" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="CreditDueValue" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="InitialOrderValue">*Value of the initial order:</label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field *Value of the initial order: must be a number." id="InitialOrderValue" name="InitialOrderValue" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="InitialOrderValue" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="StockLiftMaterialScrappedDate">Stocklift material was scrapped(Date):</label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Stocklift material was scrapped(Date): must be a date." id="StockLiftMaterialScrappedDate" name="StockLiftMaterialScrappedDate" type="datetime" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="StockLiftMaterialScrappedDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="DistributorPrincipalApprovalId">Distributor Principal (Signature):</label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="text-box single-line" id="DistributorPrincipalApprovalId" name="DistributorPrincipalApprovalId" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DistributorPrincipalApprovalId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        <b><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="DistributorPrincipalApprovalDate">Date:</label></b>
                        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date: must be a date." id="DistributorPrincipalApprovalDate" name="DistributorPrincipalApprovalDate" type="datetime" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DistributorPrincipalApprovalDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        <div id="distributorDiv">
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Comments">Comments:</label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea class="textboxComments" cols="55" id="Comments" name="Comments" rows="10">
</textarea>
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Comments" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="AdministrativeNotes">Administrative Notes:</label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea class="textboxAdministrativeNotes" cols="55" id="AdministrativeNotes" name="AdministrativeNotes" rows="10">
</textarea>
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="AdministrativeNotes" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="RejectedReason">Rejected Reason:</label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea class="textboxRejectedReason" cols="55" id="RejectedReason" name="RejectedReason" rows="10">
</textarea>
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="RejectedReason" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="FileName">Stocklift Attachment:</label></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="file" name="files" value="" multiple="multiple" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" title="Upload" id="btnUpload" onclick="javascript: getview(); return false;" />

                        <div style="color:Red;font-size:14px"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="stockliftattachmentpartial">
        
    </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <table>
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Create" name="command" class="btn btn-default" /></td></tr>
                    
                    
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Save" name="command" class="btn btn-default" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
</form><table>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left"><a href="/">Back to List</a></td>
    </tr>

</table>





                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </td>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>

    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">

     



        function getview() {

            $.get("/StockLiftAttachmentWebGrid/ShowPartial?Capacity=0&amp;Count=0)", function (data) {
                $("#stockliftattachmentpartial").replaceWith(data);
                $('#createStockLift').submit();
            });

        };
        $("#stockliftattachmentpartial").show();


        


        //{

        //    $.get("<~/Controllers/StockLiftAttachmentWebGridController/ShowPartial()>", function (data) { $("#stockliftattachmentpartial").html(data); }
        //)
        //}


        //$('#stockliftattachmentpartial').load('/Views/StockLiftAttachmentWebGrid/StockLiftAttachmentWebGrid');



    </script>

    <script>
        // var $loading = $('#divDistributor').hide();

        $(function () {
            $('#search').click(function () {
                var distributorNumber = $("#textboxDistributorNumber").val();
                var href = this.href + '?distributorNumber=' + distributorNumber;
                
                $('#dialog').dialog({
                    width: 1175,
                    height: 500,
                    title: 'Distributor Search',
                    modal: true,
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
                        $(this).load(href, function (result) {
                            $('.forms').submit(function () {

                                $.ajax({
                                    url: this.action,
                                    type: this.method,
                                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                                    success: function (json) {
                                        //$('#dialog').dialog('close');
                                        // $loading.show();
                                        debugger;
                                        $('#distributorViewModel_DistributorName').val(json.DistributorName);

                                    }
                                });
                                return false;
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Not that it appears relevant, but what is calling the `getview()` function? An `[HttpGet]` should not be able to be called from a `post`. Are there any other scripts running (mobile, SPA or ajax validation)?

Comment: The GET function should call the "Create" action and doesn't.

Comment: Can you provide the entire output HTML of the page (e.g. as saved from the browser)? That will let us quickly spot any potential problems as the snippets shown do not have any relevant clues :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Nope. Those are the only two Create actions. And I confirmed with breakpoints while debugging that the Get method is indeed getting hit! :/

Comment: That update helps: Your new piece of code shown is wiring up a submit handler, which will take over the submit process. It will not work as-is though as `serialise()` does not retain the button pressed! If you can provide the raw page output HTML that will help spot the jQuery problem.

Comment: "employee who is no longer with the company"... did he leave or was he pushed? His code smells wrong, but hard to fix without the complete picture as he is dynamically loading the form in a dialog.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I'll post the html in a second. Its a bit long!

Comment: If the theory below does not pan out, and we still can't find the problem using the page raw output HTML, are you in a position to place the site on a public facing website to inspect/debug?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I can't. If you don't see anything in the HTML snippets, no worries! You've been awesome how willing to help you are.

Comment: Just stick the raw page in a JSFiddle. I really want to know what is causing this (and never met a bug that could beat me) :)

Comment: Thanks for the update: Your first problem is your page has nested `FORM` elements. That is invalid and has to be fixed first. This may be the sole cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

Having now seen the full output page HTML, you have nested `<form>` elements which is invalid and probably causing the problems.

You need to place the forms so that they are not nested in the DOM hierarchy.

### First thoughts:

Just a theory: But if I understand the picture from the initial clues, your problem may occur when you do a "search" first. This opens a dialog, populates it with a form, then quite stupidly attaches a permanent `submit` event handler to every form that exists on the page at the time with `class="forms"`.

The following will fix that one piece of silliness:

```
      open: function (event, ui) {
         var $panel = $(this);
         $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
         $panel.load(href, function (result) {
              $('.forms', $panel).submit(function () {
```

The fix is to add a scope to the submit handler, e.g. with `$('.forms', $panel)`, so it does not steal all submits from *all `.forms` on the page*! It will target only `.forms` in the panel loaded.

Advice: Look for any other jQuery code, anywhere, that uses `submit(` and regard it as a potential problem.

Comment: Wow that fixed it! I hadn't looked closely at the rendered Html myself, and never noticed that the creator had put a form inside of his Layout view. That's why two forms were rendering. I had jumped to the conclusion that it had to do with the scripts since I have so little understanding of them. Thank you so much for your help!! (it won't let me up-vote yet because I'm a new user)

Comment: No problem. Upvote and accept when you can. Make sure you also fix that hole in the `$('.forms')` code. Cheers.